# Apply "buy X get Y" discount on N products

Tags: algebra-precalculus, percentages

Consider a product is added to a cart with quantity of **N** and "Buy X and get y" offer is applied i.e. Buy two get one free.

If n = 3 then I could simply apply a discount rate of 33.33 on each product.
But my problem occurs when there are more than 3.

If n = 4 then number of free products would still be 1 and I would have to pay full price for 4th product, but if I apply the above method I would be applying discount on the 4th product as well which should not be the case.

This continues for n = 4,5,6,7,8,9,.....

I need a formula to correctly calculate the price with the scheme applied.

Thank you.

Edit: Edited the question as it was not clear. Sorry.

X would be the number of products that needs to be purchased for the offer to apply and N would be the number of products that are actually in the cart.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simple answer is if one orders $n$ of the product you get $\lfloor \frac n3 \rfloor$ free and pay for $n-\lfloor \frac n3 \rfloor$

Comment: I don't think that will work. The discount must be on an integral number of widgets. There would only be one free widget for four purchased. Please see the example in the question, then see my answer.

Comment: That is exactly the point of the floor function.  You round the fraction down to the next whole number.  It is exactly what you asked for-the last of three is free.

Comment: Oh, you are right. I read your answer too quickly and didn't catch the notation. I'll delete my answer as it is therefore a duplicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I've edited my question to clarify X and N.

Comment: So the general formula would be 

if N >= X then we can pay for n - floor(n/x)